# Remove auto-fill text from native captive portal app

Tags: wi-fi, nexus-6, auto-fill, captive-portal

I accidentally entered my password in the username field of the captive portal and that now comes up as an auto-fill suggestion for the username, which I would like to delete/reset. This does not open up in the browser, but does so in some separate default window which I don't seem to have much control over. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the saved passwords in your browser?

Comment: @xavier_fakerat: Yup. First thing I'd tried; no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Settings > Apps, and show all system apps.

Find the CaptivePortalLogin app in the list and clear all the data for it by going to Storage > Clear Data.